# Is it possible to ping a URL after a successful Recurly transaction?

Tags: recurly

I need to ping a specific URL with a few pieces of customer data when a successful transaction is completed using Recurly.

We're currently using Ontraport and they have what are called Rules ie. If A happens then Ping URL B with Data C,D,E

It's quite simple stuff and I'm sure I'm overlooking this in the Recurly API.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 2):

Joey - when using the Hosted Payment Pages, Recurly controls the user experience, so a Success URL is used to redirect the customer after a successful signup. When using the API, however, your server is making the API call, so you can configure your flow to redirect the customer's browser as needed.